# How to select All Records from a Query based on what is entered in a combo box control on Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

I have a query called **qryFlightPrices**. It contains four fields. One of these fields is called **Favs**.

In the **Favs** field of this Query I have entered filter Criteria which references a Combo Control on a Dialog form. I entered the criteria for the Favs field like this **[Forms]![frmFlightPrices]![Favs]**

The combo controls row source is this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AirportRoutes.Favs 
FROM AirportRoutes; 
UNION Select "<All>" From AirportRoutes
ORDER BY Favs;
```

From the combo box drop down menu I have these three options:

All,

Holiday Only,

For Relocation

The query works when I select the Holiday Only and For Relocation options

**The Problem**

When I select **All** from the combo box in order to see all records from the Favs field the query doesnt return any results.

When I leave the combo blank the query also returns no results.

How can I get the query to return all results

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Change the WHERE clause of your query `qryFlightPrices` from:

```
[Favs] = [Forms]![frmFlightPrices]![Favs]
```

to:

```
1 = iif([Forms]![frmFlightPrices]![Favs] = "<All>", 1, iif([Favs] = [Forms]![frmFlightPrices]![Favs], 1, 0))
```

If I misinterpreted your WHERE clause, please supply the query, so we can work on it directly.

Comment: Thanks, do I include  1= iif at the start of the code above

Comment: No, it is in your `qryFlightPrices`. Pls post the SQL code of this query then it will be easier to help you.